# ¿Como mostrar un botón oculto al cerrar ventana de impresión en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo en una planilla, una funcion de JS para imprimir la pantalla.

Antes de hacerlo mando a ocultar el boton de imprimir y otro de volver.

Al cerrar la ventana de imprimir no aparece el boton de volver, como puedo hacer que se muestre el boton de volver e imprimir una vez regresen a la planilla.

Aqui mi codigo:

```
function imprimir(){
        document.getElementById("volver").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("imprimir").style.display = "none";
        window.print();
}

<input type="button" name="volver" id="volver" value="volver" onclick="imprimir();"></td>  

<input type="button" name="imprimir" id="imprimir" value="Imprimir" onclick="imprimir();"></td>
```

*Pense que se podria colocar que se oculto solo por unos segundos pero no se que funcion usar.*

Comment: Tienes que cambiar el estilo de `none` vuelta a `block` o `inline`, puedes hacerlo en una función callback, o en un timeout de unos pocos segundos dentro de tu función imprimir para que te la vuelva a mostrar.

Comment: @Lixus como haria eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que vuelva a aparecer una forma que puedes implementar es usando un `timeout`

```
function imprimir(){
    document.getElementById("volver").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("imprimir").style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        document.getElementById("volver").style.display = "block"; //o inline
        document.getElementById("imprimir").style.display = "block"; //o inline
    }, 3000);
    window.print();
}
```

Nada más como punto importante, 1000(ms) = 1s

Comment: Si coloco el tiempo muy bajo, corro el riesgo de que se vean en la ventana de impresion?

Comment: Ahí si ya tendrías tú que jugar con los tiempos y darle el mejor cronometrado posible para que no se muestren cuando todavía no los ocupes de vuelta.

Answer (score 2):

Una opción, sin usar Javascript, es la de crearte una hoja de estilos específica para la versión de imprimir, y dentro de esa hoja de estilos ocultar los elementos que no quieras que se impriman.

Para ello, crea un fichero que se llame "print.css". Luego, añade ese fichero a tu archivo ".html" de la siguiente manera:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Dentro del fichero css, añade las reglas para ocultar los inputs que no quieres imprimir:

```
#volver, #imprimir {
    display: none;
}
```

Así, en la pantalla se visualizarán pero en la impresión no. Y no tendrás que andar ocultando y mostrando nada por Javascript.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, pero me colocaba automáticamente oculto los botones

Comment: Para que los botones sólo se oculten al imprimir, tienes que incluir el fichero css en el <head> de. tu archivo ".html" indicando en la propiedad "media" que solo debe aplicarse para "print"

    <link href="/ruta/al/fichero/pribt.css" type="text/css" media="print" />

Debería funcionarte porque es la forma correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Usando `javascript`, puede hacer lo siguiente:

- En IE, Edge y FireFox puedes suscribirte al evento [`onafterprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint)

  > El evento `afterprint` se dispara después de que el usuario imprime o anula un diálogo de impresión.

  Ejemplo:

  ```
  window.onbeforeprint = function(){
    console.log("Impresión iniciada.");
  }
  window.onafterprint = function(){
    console.log("Impresión terminada.");
  }
  ```
- Para el resto de los navegadores puedes usar [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia).

  > Devuelve un nuevo objeto `MediaQueryList` que representa los resultados analizados de la cadena de [`media query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) especificada.

  Ejemplo:

  ```
  var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
  mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
      if (mql.matches) {
          console.log("Impresión iniciada.");
      } else {
          console.log("Impresión terminada.");
      }
  });
  ```

Demo:

```js
function imprimir(){
  if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
      printing(!!mql.matches);
    });
  }
  else if ('onbeforeprint' in window) {
    window.onbeforeprint = function(){
      printing(true);
    }
    window.onafterprint = function(){
      printing(false);
    }
  }
  
  window.print();
}

function printing(start) {
  document.getElementById("volver").style.display = start ? "none" : "inline";
  document.getElementById("imprimir").style.display = start ? "none" : "inline";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="volver" id="volver" value="volver" onclick="imprimir();">
<input type="button" name="imprimir" id="imprimir" value="Imprimir" onclick="imprimir();">
```